# HTML 5 app Download a file to the same directory as the app

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

I am using Phonegap to create a html 5 app and I would like to be able to download a file from the internet, and store it in the same directory as the app is in.
So, my app will open index.html, and in that folder the file needs to be saved.
After that, it needs to check if it has internet connection, and if not, it needs to open the file I just downloaded.
How can I do this?
I believe that if you just download it, it will go in the default download map.
Also Will there be a difference when downloading/saving this file on an android or iOs device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to be able to download a file from the internet, and store it in the same directory as the app is in.

The install location of the application is unavailable for writing in most of the platforms due to security.

However, you can write to a persistent location using the [`File`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) API.

> it needs to check if it has internet connection, and if not, it needs to open the file I just downloaded. How can I do this?

There are two parts to this, first is the check for internet connection, which can be accomplished using the [`Connection`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection) object. The latter part can again be done using the [`File`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) API.